# MX records for wildcard and subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, nameserver, mx-record, g-suite

I would like to setup the MX nameservers of a domain `domain.com` so that every income email goes to mailgun (or other inbound email processor), including all the possible subdomains `@*anything*.domain.com` **except** `@hq.domain.com` that uses Google Apps.

MX servers for Google Apps are:

```
 MX 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
 MX 5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
 MX 5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
 MX 10 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
 MX 10 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
```

MX servers for Mailgun are:

```
MX mxa.mailgun.org 
MX mxb.mailgun.org
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: its already answered, search next time @ http://serverfault.com/a/54807/315572

Comment: This question is different. I need to receive **all** the possible subdomains in mailgun, not just domain.com, except hq.domain.com that is processed by Google Apps.

Answer (score 2):

in you case

```
hq               IN      MX      1       ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
hq               IN      MX      5       ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
hq               IN      MX      5       ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
hq               IN      MX      10      ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
hq               IN      MX      10      ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
qh               IN      MX      10      ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
hq               IN      MX      10      ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@          IN      MX      10      mxa.mailgun.org.
@          IN      MX      10      mxb.mailgun.org.
*.domain.com.       IN  MX  10 mxa.mailgun.org.
*.domain.com.       IN  MX  10 mxb.mailgun.org.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will I be able to receive, for example, mails for peter@something.domain.com in Mailgun and be sure that paul@hq.domain.com is received in Google Apps?

Comment: i have edited answer and added wildcard mx, you should receive user@hq.domain.com at google apps and all other user@*.domain.com at mailgun, hope this helps

Comment: p.s : wildcard MX is documented at http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1912#section-2.7

Comment: @VasilJamalashvili The wildcard will only be used for names that don't appear explicitly in the domain. Wildcards are not type-specific, so an A record for `www.mailgun.com` will prevent the wildcard from being used for mail to `user@www.mailgun.com`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for correction, as i imagine, separate mx records must be added for each existing subdomain, i don't see any other solution.

Comment: The best solution is to configure your outgoing mail so it doesn't use subdomains in the `From` addresses, then you shouldn't have to worry about incoming mail to subdomains.

Comment: @barmar question was about incoming mail, outgoing mail will always work if there is correct mx record and ptr