# Receiving emails in a different DNS provider, should I add MX or NS records?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, dns-zone, amazon-ses, ns-record

This is similar, yet different than [How should I setup separate MX records for a subdomain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/54800/how-should-i-setup-separate-mx-records-for-a-subdomain) in that I want another DNS provider to handle receiving emails from a subdomain. I have

- a DNS zone provided by OVH (I pay for my domain name there)
- a DNS Zone on Amazon route53 (I'd like the email resolution for only my new subdomain to go here),
- I want to put my MX record to receive emails in Amazon SES ideally in my route53 DNS Zone

There is an existing email flow that I absolutely don't want to disturb : all emails sent to @mydomain.com are routed to Google DNS MX servers using MX records in my OVH DNS zone.

```
# OVH DNS Zone
domain.com. MX  5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
[and other similar records]
```

I want to create a separate subdomain email so emails sent to `@subdomain.mydomain.com` will be redirected to Amazon route 53' DNS instead but I'd like the actual MX record to remain in my Amazon route53 hosted zone record set

So the flow I want is

```
OVH > Amazon Route53 custom hosted zone > Amazon SES # (for emails @mail.domain.com)
OVH > Google DNS # (for emails @domain.com)
```

and I have already this in my Amazon route 53 Zone (I have followed the instructions to setup email receiving in Amazon SES)

```
# Amazon Route53 DNS
mail.domain.com. MX 10 inbound-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.
```

After reading several questions, I'm still not clear how emails are actually redirected, and some posts mention that MX records aren't needed for receiving emails (but in my case Amazon SES required an MX record to be somewhere)

Should I add an MX record that points to my Amazon route53 DNS
or
Should I add a NS record for my subdomain that points to my Amazon route53 DNS (so far I've been using multiple NS entries to redirect most subdomains for regular web traffic from OVH to Amazon route53's DNS)

```
# OVH > Google for @mydomain.com emails - should remain functional
domain.com. MX  5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.

# OVH > Amazon Route53 DNS 
mail.domain.com MX 10 ns-1890.awsdns-44.co.uk.  
# or 
mail.domain.com NS ns-1890.awsdns-44.co.uk.
```